# Whats the most effective way to use Jastor to create object and managedobject to store in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsmanagedobject

given objective c doesn't do multiple inheritance, what would be the best way to implement class(es) using Jastor to convert and json data source into object and also use managedobject (core data) as storage?
The whole reason for choosing Jastor was that I want to avoid laboriously code each property/field and then to have to copy the whole lot property by property into a managedobject seems dire.
But whats the most elegant way of achieving this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any `NSObject` subclass including `NSManagedObject` does just what you want out of box by means of `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol. [See example here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18814764/93540)