# Converting a txt file to an NSArray with instancetype variables

Tags: iphone, ios, database, arrays, associative-array

I created an NSObject class to store data. Currently in one of my view controllers I set an array to this data using

`NSArray *array = @[[Group groupWithName:@"name" type:@"type"], ...];`

In the class Group this is converted into an object:

`+ (instancetype)groupWithName:(NSString *)name type:(NSString *)type;`

The number of entries in this array can get rather large and I would rather have it in a text file instead. How can I convert NSStrings read in from the txt file and convert them to class (Group) objects?

Answer (score 1):

One way to put initialization of complex objects into a text file is using JSON, XML, or some custom format, and then read them at runtime from the resource, and deserialize it into objects.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8690390/335858) suggests libraries to parse JSON into objects; here is [a link to an external library that lets you do XML deserialization](http://code.google.com/p/wonderxml/). A custom format may be as simple as reading a list of key-value pairs from a file in a loop, and calling `groupWithName:type:` as you go.

The problem with this approach is that it forces your program to process strings at runtime, instead of letting the compiler do the parsing. If the only problem you're having with your current approach is the length of the code, an easy alternative is to move the array initialization into a function, put that function into a separate file, and call that function rather than embedding the lengthy piece of initialization code into your file. The end result would be similar with most of the "heavy lifting" done by the compiler at compile time.